# Link to User record, via View Contact -> Actions -> User Record gives Page Not Found (404). Is this a bug?

Tags: drupal, user-account

We are running CiviCRM 4.7.23 + Drupal 7.56.

If we try and access one of our Drupal User Records via the CiviCRM Contact record (View Contact -> Actions -> User Record) we get a 404 "Page not found" error from Drupal.

In trying to debug this, we've noticed that the URL generated by the "User Record" link in CiviCRM is like this:

```
http://oursite.org/user/XXXX&cid=YYY
```

Where XXXX is the Drupal User ID and YYY is the CiviCRM Contact ID.  If I strip off the &cid=YYY part from the URL, the link works and takes me to the correct User Record.

So, is this a bug, or is our site misconfigured somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I just tested on a site. Clicking the link as described above i get sent to

user/2&cid=39941

and that page shows.

BUT

if instead I just click on the Contact ID / User ID |
39941  / 2 that sits just under Tags on the Contact Summary screen

[image]

I get sent to

user/2 and that sounds like it might work in your set up

Does your Summary Screen not show that? (ie I wonder why you are not using that rather than going via Actions which is an extra click)

I can't explain why the link with &cid=YYY is failing for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does indeed present a useful workaround that we will likely use.  It also suggests that my problem is a misconfiguration rather than a bug.  I've given you a **useful** tick, but don't have enough reputation for that to stick.  I'll upgrade to **accept** if I don't get a better offer!

Comment: I gave your question and comment a +1 to help get you more reputable ;-)

Comment: and agree. save your 'accept' in case someone comes along and gives you an explanation about how your config might be messed up, as I can't immediately point to anything

Comment: I have run into the same issue. I think Rob Hills, you can rest assured that your configuration is correct. Every D7 site I have checked where /user/XXXX&cid=YYY results in a 404 page. If it were /user/XXXX?cid=YYY, it would be fine. 

I suppose we will just have to wait for the 4.7.26 release.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that on all sites I have access to that this is an issue. I poked around the code and can not figure out why the cid is being appended to the url
I'm going to submit this as a bug

Comment: Eric's JIRA issue is https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21247, fixed for 4.7.26 in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11057 . I've replicated the issue & verified the fix on a 4.7.23 site.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this error in two client sites and testing in CiviHosting demo by selecting user record for demo contact has the same error.  it looks like the url is missing a / before the &.   When the missing / is added to the url it goes to the correct page.

[image]

Comment: Other facts - our client sites are running civi 4.7.22 (after upgrading from 4.7.14).  Civi Hosting is running 4.7.20 so it seems to have been introduced between 4.7.14 and 4.7.20.

Comment: This AM, the same sites including CiviHosting demo work OK.   The url now is just https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com/user/2 which does not include the CID info.  Any ideas on why the URL would change?  caching issues?

Comment: Thanks Dave, my html is now a bit rusty, but I wouldn't have expected a "/" before an "&" as the latter is usually a parameter to the path, which doesn't usually terminate with a "/", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: To test Dave's hypothesis about caching being a possible cause, I tried the following:
1. Drupal: flush all caches;
2. CiviCRM: Administer -> System Settings -> Cleanup Caches;
3. CiviCRM: Administer -> System Settings -> Reset Paths.
None of these has fixed my problem, the same broken link results.

Comment: Hmm, I obviously don't understand how markdown works on this site, can't get a numbered list to display properly, sorry!

Comment: Further usage, it is not working.  Not sure if my comment about it working was based on access by clicking on the drupal user ID in the contact record.    Also, I think the extra / was the equivalent of stripping the &cid=YYY suggestion.   So, I don't think it is a configuration issue based on the number of sites including demo that have the issue.